Where to get a demo/fake/dummy Windows device device that does nothing?
I like to test programmatically uninstalling a driver, but I don't like to break an actual driver.
Can one find online a demo/fake/dummy device driver that can be installed but does nothing?
Kind of like Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter, but without doing anything (this one installs a whole Ethernet adapter).

Many years ago I was forced to install a  "'Generic (Text-only)' print driver for Windows" driver:  not sure if this may help you, but it is the simplest driver I can think of
BTW: it could worth mentioning that, given that virtual printer was the only one installed on my windows platform, all the non-fixed fonts became disabled/hidden (not sure if this has been fixed or not - YMMV)

Thanks, but where to find it? Although in any case it still installs a printer which is undesirable.

maybe you can search for "install a null driver" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/installing-a-null-driver

otherwise if you like to stick with the text only printer:
no external software needed: this virtual/null driver is shipped with  the OS (the first result with images provided by google when searching for  generic text only printer driver
was this https://help.aronium.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019413520-Add-Generic-Text-only-printer )

That null driver example just fails to install as if Microsoft's code is wrong (maybe outdated), but I suspect even if it worked it would fail due to being unsigned.

The Windows Driver Samples repo (from Microsoft) offers you an official selection of drivers to build yourself including "Hello World" drivers. I am sure that you can find something to meet your needs there.
You will also need to read the Microsoft tutorial on "test signing" drivers.

Problem is they won't be signed, right? Meaning nowadays it'll be impossible to use them unless restarting in driver unsigned mode.

@LWC - You can "test sign" them - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/signing-a-driver-during-development-and-testing for how.

If I understand correctly, the undesirable restarting part is for self-signs (for no signing at all even the special mode restart won't help).
